# Crash Ubuntu 20.04 systemd-journal Failed to write entry. Ignoring: read-only

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, crash

I speak spanish and I do not speak English well

I have a problem with Ubuntu 20

I am working with the computer, with any program and the computer crashes and the following message appears

> "systemd-journal Failed to write entry. Ignoring: read-only file system only"

After shutting down the computer sometimes I can work.
Other times it doesn't start and stays in the grub without starting. It only presents the prompt.

The same thing happened to me a while ago and I solved it by installing ubunto on another disk. I thought it was a hardware write error

sda - I have installed an empty ubuntu. It's the oldest ssh
sdb - is the disk I work on. It's the new ssh

To recover the system I start with ubuntu in sda
I have / in sdb4

I run:

> sudo fsck /dev/sdb4 -y

```
fsck de util-linux 2.34

e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)

/dev/sdb4: recuperando el archivo de transacciones

Se ha encontrado un error en el fichero de transacciones en /dev/sdb4

  Borrando nodo-i huérfano 48248442 (uid=1000, gid=1000, modo=0100664, tamaño=32768)

  Borrando nodo-i huérfano 48248441 (uid=1000, gid=1000, modo=0100600, tamaño=71416)

  Borrando nodo-i huérfano 48628672 (uid=1000, gid=1000, modo=0100664, tamaño=0)

  Borrando nodo-i huérfano 48628664 (uid=1000, gid=1000, modo=0100664, tamaño=0)

  Borrando nodo-i huérfano 48628657 (uid=1000, gid=1000, modo=0100664, tamaño=0)

  Borrando nodo-i huérfano 22807588 (uid=1000, gid=1000, modo=0100600, tamaño=0)

  /dev/sdb4 no fue desmontado limpiamente, se fuerza la revisión.

  Paso 1: Verificando nodos-i, bloques y tamaños

  Paso 2: Verificando la estructura de directorios    

  Paso 3: Revisando la conectividad de directorios

  Paso 4: Revisando las cuentas de referencia

  Paso 5: Revisando el resumen de información de grupos

  La cuenta de bloques libres es incorrecta (149233341, contados=149226606).

  ¿Arreglar? sí

  La cuenta de nodos-i libres es incorrecta (60500042, contados=60500033).

  ¿Arreglar? sí

  /dev/sdb4: ***** EL SISTEMA DE FICHEROS FUE MODIFICADO *****

  /dev/sdb4: 513983/61014016 ficheros (1.1% no contiguos), 94806162/244032768 bloques
```

And I run

> sudo badblocks -s -v -n -f /dev/sdb

and returns 0 errors after several hours of work

Then the system works again for a couple of days

I am thinking of reinstalling everything.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: are you usning btrfs in your root partitions?